# NETLOGO Set a variable of an agent to something

Tags: variables, netlogo

I want to set variable  P of one of the turtles with happy? = true to P - 9. 
This is what i have so far, but it is not working, any ideas?

```
set [P] of one-of turtles with [happy? = true] (P - 9)
```

Comment: Tyr's answer is correct. Side comment: you don't need to say `with [happy? = true]`, you can use `happy?` directly, as in `with [happy?]`.

Answer (score 1):

`[P] of ...` can only report the value of the turtles variable, but you are not allowed to change it because you are not in the turtles context.
You have to call the turtle via ask to change its own variable:

```
   ask one-of turtles with [happy? = true]
    [
      set P (P - 9)
    ]
```